# Distinguish bool from integers 0 and 1 in list

Tags: python, boolean

```
s = [0, 1, True]
```

I have a list, I want to find True and access it. I know that `False == 0`, `True == 1`, is there really no way not to loop through it?

```
print(s.index(True)) # output: 1
print(s.count(True)) # output: 2
```

I've tried converting `bool` to `str`, and comparing it to the string `'True'` and then wrapping the response in `bool()`. I've tried comparing `type()`, but I'd like to know how to do this more elegantly than iterating every element.

Comment: You will have to iterate every element until you found a result. `index` and `count` do the same.

Comment: The problem is thate those functions use **equality**, not identity. You probably have to write a custom `index_identity(iterable, needle)` using a `elem is needle` check, since `1 is True` returns `False`.

Comment: `count` could be implemented as `sum(isinstance(x, bool) and x for x in s)`.

Comment: For `index` I came up with `next(filter(lambda x: isinstance(x[1], bool) and x[1], enumerate(s)), (-1, None))[0]`, but there might be better solutions.

Comment: _I want to find True and access it_ - what exactly do you want to do [with it]? Do you really need the index? This smells like XY problem

Comment: `for item in s: if item is True: print("found")` does exactly what you seem to be asking. I agree that this is probably an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: @Matthias, how it's work? `next(filter(lambda x: isinstance(x[1], bool) and x[1], enumerate(s)), (-1, None))[0]`

Comment: @ТимофейМакаров It's hard to explain if you don't know how `next`, `filter` and `enumerate` work. But all of those [built-in functions are documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html). You could start to explore the inner part and look at the result of `for x in enumerate(s): print(x)`.

Comment: It's unclear. The ```index()``` and ```count()``` run a loop internally. So, are you asking on a built-in or standard library API for your specific need? Then, there's no such API. Implement it by yourself. It's pretty simple.

Comment: My solution for the index function was too complicated. `next(filter(lambda x: x[1] is True, enumerate(s)), (-1, None))[0]` is enough.